# The ring $\{\frac{1}{2}(a+b\sqrt{2})\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So I know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is an integral domain, but I don't understand why $\{\frac{1}{2}(a+b\sqrt{2}): a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ isn't an integral domain.

Answer (score 6):

It's not even a ring, let alone an integral domain. For instance
$$
\Big(\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{2})\Big)^2 = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2} = \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{3}{2} + \sqrt{2}\Big)
$$

Comment: Facepalm on my part. I just assumed that it was a ring. Woops.

Comment: You may be able to tweak it and make it a ring with some modified definition. If finally you end up with a set that is a subset of real/complex numbers, if it is a ring it will be an integral domain. Because subrings of integral domains/fields will again be integral domains.  But no guarantee about unique factorization property.

Answer (score 5):

It's just that $$A = \left\{\frac{1}{2}(a+b\sqrt{2}): a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$ is not a ring, as
$$
\frac{1}{2} \in A,
\qquad
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} \notin A.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The product $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$ is not in your "ring" although $\frac{1}{2}$ is..